# How do I remove underscores from the first word of everyline?

Tags: regex, notepad++

I need to remove _ from the first word of every line of the following:

```
Hd_pin = row["HD_PIN"];
Hd_vol = row["HD_VOL"];
Hd_town = row["HD_TOWN"];
Hd_pri_lnd = row["HD_PRI_LND"];
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This works in notepad++.

Globally,
find: `(?m)(?:(?!^)\G|^\h*)[^\W_]*\K_`
replace with nothing

https://regex101.com/r/sQVNZm/1

Readable

```
 (?m)                 # Multi-line mode
 (?:
      (?! ^ )              # Not BOL
      \G                   # Start where last match left off
   |                     # or,
      ^ \h*                # BOL, optional horizontal wsp
 )
 [^\W_]*              # Optional words, not underscore
 \K                   # Ignore up to here
 _                    # Until the next underscore
```

Answer (score 1):

Look for

```
^_*?([^_=]+)_?
```

Replace by:

```
$1
```

You may need to run the operation several times until Notepad++ says "Can't find the text..."

By the way, don't forget to select "Regular Expression" in the Search Mode section.

Edit: added fix, just in case the first word begins with _